# Alternative to modify Core XML

Tags: civievent, best-practice

I need to make a minor change to CRM/Core/xml/Menu/Admin.xml so that people that manage events can also schedule email reminders, exactly like Lobo describes the answer here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=28431.0

I know that we can make custom changes to tpl files without changing core files, is it possible to also make a change to an XML from this particular directory?

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating you own extension with your own xml file that use the same path as the one you want to change.

You should use [civix](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension) to create the core file of the extension. The new extension needs only 3 files :

- info.xml (to be completed after civix has generated it)
- yourextension.civix.php (you don't have to touch this one)
- yourextension.php (only touch it if you need additionnal customization like hook call)

Then you just have to add a xml file in `yourextensionpath/xml/Menu/` that contains the modified menu entry like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
 <menu>
   <item>
     <path>civicrm/admin/scheduleReminders</path>
     <title>Schedule Reminders</title>
     <desc>Schedule Reminders.</desc>
     <access_arguments>administer CiviCRM;access CiviEvent</access_arguments>
     <path_arguments>action=update</path_arguments> (also tried with <path_arguments>group=scheduleReminders</path_arguments>)
     <page_callback>CRM_Admin_Page_ScheduleReminders</page_callback>
     <adminGroup>Communications</adminGroup>
     <icon>admin/small/template.png</icon>
     <weight>40</weight>
   </item>
 </menu>
```

After activating your extension, you may have to go visit `civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1` to clean the cache.